# How to detect latin word in a file in mulesoft

Tags: mule

I want to detect latin / non-english word in a file in a Mule application running in Anypoint Studio (MuleSoft products), Can anyone help me?

Basically my code fetching a file from a legacy system and read it and post the data to salesforce, while reading the file I need to detect if any latin word / non-english word are there in the name column

Comment: Please define latin words. Do you mean words in the latin language spoken in the late roman empire?

Comment: @aled any latin or non english alphabet ....it should detect any non-english alphabet while reading the file

Comment: What is the format of the input file? You have to provide an example.

Comment: are symbols like !,?. etc a possibility? And if yes then do you also want to "detect" them?

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in function to detect characters outside the english alphabet that I'm aware of in Mule.

One alternative is to create a custom DataWeave function and use the [charCode()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-strings-functions-charcode) or [charCodeAt()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-strings-functions-charcodeat) functions to compare the Unicode characters of each character in the file with the allowed english characters, iterating over the characters of the file. This assumes that the file is a text file that can be read as a string.

Another alternative is to implement the same algorithm in a Java class and call it using the [Java Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/java-module/1.2/).

This is a solution with DataWeave using a recursive function to iterate over the characters. It would be more efficient if there was a way to avoid the recursion:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Strings
fun isEnglishChar(c)= 
        (c >= 65 and c <= 90) or (c >= 97 and c <= 122) or (c == 32)

fun isEnglishWord(s)=
    if (sizeOf(s) > 1) isEnglishChar(charCode(s)) and isEnglishWord(s[1 to -1])
    else if (sizeOf(s) == 1) isEnglishChar(charCode(s))
    else true
---
payload map isEnglishWord($.name)
```

Input:

```
[
{
    "name": "has space"
},
{
    "name": "JustEnglish"
},
{
    "name": "ñó"
}]
```

Output:

```
[
  true,
  true,
  false
]
```

Using functions makes it easy to reuse and to modify the logic if needed.

Comment: I added a DataWeave script with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to parse input and get the string value in name field. You can iterate over the String value and for each word in the string, apply the below logic on each word.

Logic: Assuming the word is either english word or non-english word, pick the first letter from the word and check if it contains in the 26 english alphabets. When English word, value of No_Latin_Word should be True else False.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

//var name = "ĥć"
var name = "hc"
---
No_Latin_Word : upper(name[0]) contains /[A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z]/
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below regex to find non-English words, created a simple example as below

**input**:

```
{
"message": "你好"
}
```

**code:**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.message contains (/[^\x00-\x7F]+/)
```

**output :**  true

one more working example screenshot is as below:
[image]